Apply custom class to mat-tab in mat-tab-group
I want to apply custom styles to some mat-tabs inside mat-tab-group based on a condition.
The parent mat-tab-group already has a custom style by default that works as expected. Here's how that's done:
.mat-mdc-tab-group.round-tabs,
.mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar.round-tabs {
  .mdc-tab {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

However, I am unable to apply any sort of condition based custom style on mat-tab. Here's a Stackblitz to show what I have so far. Would appreciate help of any sort to get this done, thanks!

Quick search gave this opportunity
[labelClass]="option.highlight ? 'highlight' : ''"

And in component css:
::ng-deep .highlight {
  background-color: red !important;
}

